# How to check if password answer matches what is provided by a user in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, membership, password-recovery, membershipuser

I simply want to know how to manually check if the value a user has provided for the answer to their security question matches their current answer on record.  I want to use the build in support of the ASP.Net membership and membershipuser objects.

I see that via the passwordrecovery control that the actual answer can be returned.  However I am currently not using this control and it would take a good bit to integrate it as it does not meet our user's requirements.

In a worst case scenario, getting the actual answer (like the passwordrecovery control does) and manually checking it in our application would be acceptable.

A best case scenario is some sort of API where I can pass in the user name and the answer to their security question that was provided and simply get an indication of whether answer was correct or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: got any answer? i am also looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the user via `Membership.GetUser`, then call the [GetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx96zecz.aspx) method on the user. A `MembershipPasswordException` will be thrown if the answer is wrong.

If you're looking to immediately reset the password, calling the correct `ResetPassword` overload directly might be a better idea.